# How to install AMD rocm in Apple imac pro 2017 (to further install tensorflow for Deep Learning)

Tags: macos, tensorflow, deep-learning, macos-sierra

I didn't find any way after thoroughly searched in the web to install AMD rocm (libraries for AMD graphics card for GPU computing to run deep learning - like tensorflow) for iMac pro 2017 desktop.

As per rocm (https://rocm.github.io/ROCmInstall.html) the only operating system

- Ubuntu 16.04 &. 18.04 (Version 16.04.3 and newer or kernels 4.13 and
  newer)
- CentOS 7.4 &. 7.5 (Using devetoolset-7 runtime support)
- RHEL 7.4. &. 7.5 (Using devetoolset-7 runtime support)

Also, Apple iMac pro 2017 provided very powerful AMD graphics Card (`Radeon Pro Vega 56 8176 MB`), where the benchmark shows its equivalent to

Does this mean, we can't install rocm on mac (as it's not supported / version is not available for mac)?

OR

Has anyone successfully installed the rocm on mac have AMD graphics card built it and installed & run the tensorflow for Rocm Software Platform (https://github.com/ROCmSoftwarePlatform/tensorflow-upstream)

Answer (score 3):

Based on there being an open bug about adding mac support since about a year now (https://github.com/RadeonOpenCompute/ROCm/issues/262) I'd venture to say the answer is currently no.

Answer (score 0):

According to this issue(https://github.com/RadeonOpenCompute/ROCm/issues/262), there is no clear plan for developing macos-compatible rocm."ROCm is based on customized linux kernel. so there is no compatibility with Unix kernel."

and I found a post about how to use do deep learning on mac with amd gpu([@danbrice medium article](https://medium.com/@danbrice.datascience/deep-learning-on-a-mac-with-amd-gpu-4be1f18944a)),hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

AMD ROCm support through [PyTorch 1.8](https://pytorch.org/blog/pytorch-1.8-released/#beta-amd-gpu-binaries-now-available) (Beta) launched a few hours ago! You can see the commands to install it based on your development environment [here](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/).